# What's an efficient way to insert new corresponding element into array from another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. One with US States abbreviations and ids, and another one containing again States abbreviations and other data, like so:
Array 1:

```
 Array
    (
        [1] => AL
        [2] => AK
        [3] => AZ
        [4] => CA
        [5] => FL
        [6] => MA
        [7] => IL
    )
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AK
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FL
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => AK
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => CA
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => CA
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => FL
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => AL
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => IL
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => AL
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => AZ
            [1] => Other State Data
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => MA
            [1] => Other State Data
        )
)
```

I am trying to end up by comparing the 2 arrays and inserting into the second one, the key position of the first array, when there is abbreviation match. So the end result should be like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AK
            [1] => Other State Data
            [2] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FL
            [1] => Other State Data
            [2] => 5
        )
 ... and so on...
```

Is there any appropriate handy function that I should consider to use? If not, how an efficient paradigm would look? Looping over the array and checking each member?

*excuse me for not using quotes for the array values and sorry for my english if those sound bad.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried this at all, but in theory it should work. Loop over the second array since that's the one you'll modify, and search for the state code in the first array. If found, add it's key to your second array:

```
foreach ($secondArray as &$values) {
    list ($state, $otherData) = $values;
    $stateKey = array_search($state, $firstArray);
    if (false !== $stateKey) {
        $values[] = $stateKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First flip key/values of abbreviations/ids array, then modify main data array with `array_walk`:

```
$flipped = array_flip( $abbreviationsArray );
array_walk( $data, function( &$item ) use( $flipped ) {
    if( isset( $flipped[ $item[0] ] ) ) $item[] = $flipped[ $item[0] ];
});
```

`array_walk` process each data array element: for each element — if in flipped array there is an element with same key as current element[0] — we add it as element[2].

At the end `$data` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AK
            [1] => Other State Data
            [2] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FL
            [1] => Other State Data
            [2] => 5
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => AK
            [1] => Other State Data
            [2] => 2
    (...)
)
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/553612)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your answer and demo, interesting approach. I ll go with Robbie's answer though, as it performs a bit faster.